# Did the Soviets have an official campaign to remove foreign nationals to Siberia?

Tags: world-war-two, soviet-union

Specifically, in the Ukraine. And more specifically, to remove foreign nationals out of the way of the impending German invasion during WW 2?

The intent and impact always intersect. But the question still stands.

Comment: So they were allegedly sending foreign nationals to Siberia to protect them or because they were seen as a risk?

Comment: Welcome to History:SE.  What has your research shown you so far?  Where have you already searched?  What did you find?  Why was that insufficient?  Please help us to help you. You might find it helpful to review or  site [tour] and [help], and in particular, [ask].

Answer (score 2):

There used to be the [Volga German Autonomous Soviet Socialist Republic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volga_German_Autonomous_Soviet_Socialist_Republic) (VG ASSR), a part of the Russian Soviet Federative Socialist Republic (RSFSR), which was disestablished on 28 August 1941. According to the 1939 census, 366,685 native Germans lived there. (60.5% of the total population). When Germany invaded the USSR in 1941, the VG ASSR was disestablished and all those native Germans exiled to the Kazakh SSR and Siberia. Many were interned in labor camps merely due to their heritage.

That was all. But after the war, [several other nations were also exiled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forced_settlements_in_the_Soviet_Union) to Siberia and Central Asia for alleged collaboration with the Nazis, the main ones were Crimean Tatars, Chechens, Ingushes, Kalmyks, and several others.

Comment: This would be greatly improved if you could add links to supporting sources for the groups exiled after the war.

Comment: There was not only the Volga German ASSR, but also a number of German settlements further to the west. Some had been given up due to the Heim ins Reich policy in 1939/1940, but according to wikipedia others (e.g. in Crimea and Eastern Ukraine) were deported to Siberia and Central Asia. Not sure if this is relevant to the question, though, since I would assume these were mostly Soviet nationals with German ethnicity.
 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Sea_Germans

Comment: Also the Germans were not the first to be deported. Again according to wikipedia, Koreans were deported to Central Asia in 1937 already: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koryo-saram

Answer (score 1):

This is a very unclear question.

Yes, generally speaking, anyone who might be suspected of an outside loyalty was likely to be persecuted. E.g., 400k out of 700k people executed during the [Great Purge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Purge) were Poles (according to [Bloodlands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloodlands)).

If you are specifically asking about the spring of 1941 - no. No German invasion (and certainly its extent!) was *expected*. However, as the war unfolded, [plenty of ethnic groups were deported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forced_settlements_in_the_Soviet_Union), both as a "preventive" and as "punitive" measures.

Comment: Thanks sds. When my father and his family chose to go east with the Russian army when the final borders of Poland were determined, when they got to Ukraine from Poland, they were transported east. Turns out it saved their lives. I could not find anything to suggest a relocation campaign for Polish nationals coming over the border in late 1939. But maybe?

Comment: The Russian army did NOT "go east" "when the final borders of Poland were determined".

Comment: @okidoki If your question is related to family heritage you might consider asking it on [Genealogy & Family History SE](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com)